# How to benchmark speed of load/readRDS correctly in R?

Tags: r, microbenchmark

I was thinking about efficient reading data into R and tried several ways to test if `load('file.Rdata')` or `readRDS('file.rds')` is faster. The files *file.Rdata* and *file.rds* contain the same data, the first created with `save(d, 'file.Rdata', compress=F)` and the second with `saveRDS(d, 'file.rds', compress=F)`.

First I used the function `microbenchmark()` and was a astonished about the max value of the output.

FIRST TEST:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
    n <- readRDS('file.rds'),
    load('file.Rdata')
)


Unit: milliseconds
expr                      min        lq          mean        median      uq          max          neval
n <- readRDS('file.rds')  106.5956   109.6457    237.3844    117.8956    141.9921    10934.162    100
load(fl2)                 295.0654   301.8162    335.6266    308.3757    319.6965    1915.706     100
```

It looks like the max value is an outlier.

So I tried: 
SECOND TEST:

```
sapply(1:10, function(x) system.time(n <- readRDS('file.rds'))[3])
elapsed  elapsed  elapsed  elapsed  elapsed  elapsed  elapsed  elapsed  elapsed  elapsed 
10.50    0.11     0.11     0.11     0.10     0.11     0.11     0.11     0.12     0.12 

sapply(1:10, function(x) system.time(load'flie.Rdata'))[3])
elapsed  elapsed  elapsed  elapsed  elapsed  elapsed  elapsed  elapsed  elapsed  elapsed
1.86     0.29     0.31     0.30     0.30     0.31     0.30     0.29     0.31     0.30
```

Which confirmed my suspicion; the first time loading the data takes much longer than the following times. I suspect that this has something to do how the data is assigned and that R doesn't has to 'fully' read the data, if it is read the second time.

So the question remains, how can I make a realistic benchmark test? From the first test I would conclude that reading the *.rds file is faster. But this holds only for a large number of neval. If I set `times = 1` then reading the *.Rdata would be faster (as also indicated by the second test).

Thanks for any help or comments.

Kind regards

Comment: Does the "first read is very slow" behaviour repeat if you exit your R session and quickly re-start a new one? If so, then perhaps the OS is caching the file the first time it is read from disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some replies from the R-help@r-project.org list, which I try to summarize here. All answers can be found [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg245400.html) and [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg245408.html).

Following the idea of William Dunlap to force garbage collection, I ended up with the following code:

```
library(microbenchmark)
mb <- microbenchmark(
    gc1 <- gc(),
    n <- readRDS('file.rds'),
    rm(n),
    gc2 <- gc(),
    load('file.Rdata'),
    rm(objectRdata),
    gc3 <- gc(),
    times=1000, control = list(order="inorder", warmup=4)
)
```

However, when extracting the times with `mb$time[mb$expr=="d <- readRDS('file.rds')"]` and `mb$time[mb$expr=="load('file.Rdata')"]` it was still the first value, which was much larger than all the following. Strangely, reading data with `readRDS` for the first time to the longest (around 10 sec), whereas the first time loading with `load` took around 2 sec. The following reading with `readRDS` were around 0.14 sec whereas `load` needed 0.32 sec.

Up to this point the files were stored on a server. I tried the same with the files stored locally on C:.

When reading/loading the local files all the readings were closer together with smaller values for `readRDS`of 0.14 sec vs. 0.33 sec for `load`

To conclude. The reading/loading depends on the file location and `readRDS` of uncompressed files is faster than `load`. However keep in mind the answer of Ismail Sezen given at R-help@r-project.org:

> Why are there 2 functions called *readRDS* and *load*?
>
> Because they have different purposses. You use _load _function to read/load 
>   bulk saved variables by *save* function and you use *readRDS* function to 
>   read/load a single variable saved by *saveRDS* function. So, it is inevitable 
>   both functions are optimized for different purposes. This is something like 
>   compare apple and pear altough both are fruits. Sometimes you want to eat apple 
>   but sometimes pear.
>
> Aas a result, if I need to save and read a single R object, I prefer 
>   readRDS/saveRDS couple. If I need to serialize multiple object to a file, I use 
>   the load/save couple.